# Edge won't go away, no matter what I try, and it can't be selected

Tags: modeling, edges, faces

theres a loose edge in my blend file and i tried delete loose, clean up, remove doubles, EVERYTHING. i worked hard on this model and i can't let it go to waste. anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Screenshot please?

Comment: sorry, i was refreshing the home page, and it said i was the last one to interact with this question so i didnt see this. theres one in the post now. :)

Comment: You have two edges selected, which do you want to remove? Normally I'd say make sure only that one is selected, then press `Delete` *> Edges* or `Delete` *> Dissolve Edges*. Does this not work?

Comment: the orange one isn't selected, just looks it. it needs to be deleted.

Comment: but it is refusing to be selected

Comment: So after hitting `A` it is still selected?

Comment: Try deleting one of the end vertices and re-creating the affected faces.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20538/discussion-between-noviceindisguise-and-aidan-pallian).

Comment: I think the orange edge is a separate object. switch to edit-mode and try again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The edge is a *separate object* from the rest of the mesh; it appears orange because it was also selected when you entered edit-mode. <kbd>Tab</kbd> into object mode, deselect the main object so that the only object selected is the mystery edge, and delete. (<kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd>)

Answer (score 1):

In *Edit Mode* I had to switch from the vertices selection mode to the edge selection mode, and that worked. [This part of the interface](https://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/selecting-vertices-edges-and-faces-in-blender/).

To switch to the edges mode, it is the second button next to the *Edit mode* here. Then press the  <kbd>Del</kbd> key on the keyboard to get the delete popup and delete *Edges*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just had this exact same thing happen to me.. I had to go back into object mode, and then into edit mode in order to select it..